# connect nodes with NEXT replation by date

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

i have this sample graph:

http://console.neo4j.org/?id=mginka

and i'm trying to find a Cypher code,that will connect all the hits nodes of each session by the date_time field with [NEXT] relation –
hits from different sessions shouldn't be connected..

thanks,
Lior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your console graph, this query do the trick :

```
MATCH (session:Session)
MATCH (session)<-[:IN_SESSION]-(hit)
WITH session, hit
ORDER BY hit.date_time ASC 
WITH session, collect(hit) AS hits 
UNWIND range(1, size(hits)-1) AS hitKey
MATCH (prev) WHERE id(prev) = id(hits[hitKey-1])
MATCH (current) WHERE id(current) = id(hits[hitKey])
MERGE (prev)-[:NEXT]->(current)
```